# How to calculate prior year sales data in SQL

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, case, union

I'm attempting to build a table summarizing sales data by week. In it, I'm trying to have one of the adjacent columns show the sales figures for the same fiscal week during the prior year (which due to my organizations fiscal calendar, had a 53rd week last year). I also have need to compare (Comp Units/Comp Sales) to a period 52 weeks ago which is an entirely different fiscal week (Think Week 9 of 2019 comparing to Week 10 2018).

I've tried using both unions and full outer joins, but given the way the way my data is, they're inefficient (Because this is weekly data, unions ended up being inefficient as I needed to leave the date information out of the initial query, then updating columns in my table to reflect the week the data is for. This is obviously rife with opportunity for error, but also time consuming to do 105 times), or just didn't work (attempting a full outer join was returning the wrong answers for all columns). I've also tried utilizing CTEs as well, and that's not working for me either. I'm currently trying a CASE Statement, but that's also returning a null value. I'm not quite sure where to go next

```
#STANDARDSQL
SELECT 
 DTL.SKU_NBR                                                      AS SKU_NBR
, SLS.STR_NBR                                                     AS STR_NBR
, CONCAT(TRIM(CAST(SKU_HIER.SKU_NBR AS STRING)), ' ', '-', ' ', TRIM(SKU_HIER.SKU_DESC))                                          AS SKU
, CONCAT(TRIM(CAST(SKU_HIER.EXT_SUB_CLASS_NBR AS STRING)), ' ', '-', ' ', TRIM(SKU_HIER.SUB_CLASS_DESC))                                    AS SUB_CLASS
, CONCAT(TRIM(CAST(SKU_HIER.EXT_SUB_SC_NBR AS STRING)), ' ', '-', ' ', TRIM(SKU_HIER.SUB_SC_DESC))                                 AS SUB_SUB_CLASS
, LOCATION.MKT_NM                                           AS MARKET_NAME
, LOCATION.RGN_NM                                           AS REGION_NAME
, LOCATION.DIV_NM                                           AS DIVISION_NAME
, LOCATION.DIV_NBR                                          AS DIVISION_NUMBER
, LOCATION.RGN_NBR                                          AS REGION_NUMBER
, LOCATION.MKT_NBR                                          AS MARKET_NUMBER
, COMP.STR_COMP_IND                                         AS COMP_IND
, COMP.PY_STR_COMP_IND                                      AS PRIOR_COMP_IND
, CALENDAR.FSCL_WK_DESC                                     AS FISCAL_WEEK
, CALENDAR.FSCL_PRD_DESC                                    AS FISCAL_PERIOD
, CALENDAR.FSCL_WK_END_DT                                   AS END_DATE
, CALENDAR.FSCL_WK_BGN_DT                                   AS BEGIN_DATE
, CALENDAR.FSCL_YR                                          AS FISCAL_YEAR_NBR
, CALENDAR.FSCL_WK_NBR                                      AS WEEK_NUMBER
, CALENDAR.FSCL_YR_WK_KEY_VAL                               AS FISCAL_KEY
, CALENDAR.LY_FYR_WK_KEY_VAL                                AS LY_FISCAL_KEY
, SUM(COALESCE(DTL.UNT_SLS,0))                              AS UNITS
, SUM(COALESCE(DTL.EXT_RETL_AMT,0) + COALESCE(DTL.TOT_GDISC_DTL_AMT,0))                                                                                        
                                                            AS SALES
, SUM(CASE
            WHEN 1=1 THEN (COALESCE(DTL.EXT_RETL_AMT,0) + COALESCE(DTL.TOT_GDISC_DTL_AMT,0)) * COMP.STR_COMP_IND
            ELSE 0 END)                                     AS COMP_SALES
, SUM(CASE
            WHEN 1=1 THEN (COALESCE(DTL.UNT_SLS,0)) * COMP.STR_COMP_IND
            ELSE 0 END)                                     AS COMP_UNITS
, SUM(CASE
            WHEN 1=1 AND SLS.SLS_DT = DATE_SUB(SLS.SLS_DT, INTERVAL 364 DAY) 
            THEN (COALESCE(DTL.EXT_RETL_AMT,0) + 
            COALESCE(DTL.TOT_GDISC_DTL_AMT,0)) * COMP.PY_STR_COMP_IND
            ELSE NULL END)                                                                                                                                                 
                                                            AS LY_COMP_SALES
, SUM(CASE
            WHEN 1=1 AND SLS.SLS_DT = DATE_SUB(SLS.SLS_DT, INTERVAL 364 DAY)  
            THEN (COALESCE(DTL.UNT_SLS,0)) * COMP.PY_STR_COMP_IND
            ELSE NULL END)                                                                                                                                                 
                                                            AS LY_COMP_UNITS
, SUM(CASE 
            WHEN SLS.SLS_DT = DATE_SUB(SLS.SLS_DT, INTERVAL 371 DAY) 
            THEN (COALESCE(DTL.EXT_RETL_AMT,0) + 
            COALESCE(DTL.TOT_GDISC_DTL_AMT,0)) 
            ELSE NULL END)                                                                                                               
                                                            AS LY_SALES
, SUM(CASE 
            WHEN SLS.SLS_DT = DATE_SUB(SLS.SLS_DT, INTERVAL 371 DAY) 
            THEN (COALESCE(DTL.UNT_SLS,0)) 
            ELSE NULL END)                                                                                                               
                                                            AS LY_UNITS


FROM `pr-edw-views.SLS.POS_SLS_TRANS_DTL`                   AS SLS

INNER JOIN 
  UNNEST (SLS.DTL)                                          AS DTL 


JOIN `pr-edw-views.SHARED.MVNDR_HIER`                       AS MVNDR  
  ON DTL.DERIV_MVNDR.MVNDR_NBR = MVNDR.MVNDR_NBR

JOIN `pr-edw-views.SHARED.SKU_HIER_FD`                      AS SKU_HIER
  ON SKU_HIER.SKU_NBR = DTL.SKU_NBR
  AND SKU_HIER.SKU_CRT_DT = DTL.SKU_CRT_DT 

JOIN `pr-edw-views.SHARED.LOC_HIER_FD`                      AS LOCATION
  ON LOCATION.LOC_NBR = SLS.STR_NBR

JOIN `pr-edw-views.SHARED.CAL_PRD_HIER_FD`                  AS CALENDAR
  ON CALENDAR.CAL_DT = SLS_DT

JOIN `pr-edw-views.SLS.STR_COMP_DAY`                        AS COMP
  ON COMP.CAL_DT = CALENDAR.CAL_DT
  AND COMP.STR_NBR = SLS.STR_NBR


WHERE CALENDAR.FSCL_WK_END_DT BETWEEN '2018-01-29' AND '2019-04-07'
AND SLS.SLS_DT BETWEEN '2018-01-29' AND '2019-04-07'
AND POS_TRANS_TYP_CD in ('S', 'R')
AND SKU_HIER.EXT_CLASS_NBR = '025-004'
AND MVNDR.MVNDR_NBR IN (74798, 60002238, 73059, 206820, 76009, 40263, 12879, 76722, 10830, 206823, 87752, 60052261, 70401, 51415, 51414)
AND SKU_HIER.LATEST_SKU_CRT_DT_FLG = TRUE


GROUP BY
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
```

I'm currently getting null values in my `LY_SALES`, `LY_UNITS`, `LY_COMP_SALES` and `LY_COMP_UNITS` columns, though I know there should have been locations with sales of those items from the same period the previous year. What I'm trying to get to is having those prior year values showing up along side the current year values. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Such a condition can never be fulfilled : SLS.SLS_DT = DATE_SUB(SLS.SLS_DT, INTERVAL 371 DAY). Simply because a SLS_DT is not equal to SLS_DT-371.

You can pre-aggregate the table in a CTE (adding SLS_DT to the group by columns) and then replace the CASE with a join to the pre-aggregated table. Aim at something like this: and it will become something like (notice - no SUM in the case):

```
CASE WHEN AGGSLS.SLS_DT = DATE_SUB(SLS.SLS_DT, INTERVAL 371 DAY) 
THEN (COALESCE(AGGSLS.SUM_EXT_RETL_AMT,0) + 
COALESCE(AGGSLS.SUM_TOT_GDISC_DTL_AMT,0)) 
ELSE NULL END
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
1) `WHEN 1=1` can be expressed simply as `WHEN TRUE`, this way it is easier to move statements around without breaking the AND/OR chaining

2) to get the last year's sales. You can either omit the year from the final query and limit the output with a where clause or create a smaller table that has the sales this year, sales last year per week.

In my humble opinion sales last year for weeknum is the best option, as you can use it elsewhere. But it's pretty similar to what you wr

It would look something like:

```
SELECT CALENDAR.FSCL_WK_DESC as week_num,
sum(case when year = year(current_date()) then (COALESCE(DTL.UNT_SLS,0)) * COMP.STR_COMP_IND else 0 end) as this_year
sum(case when year = year(current_date())-1 then (COALESCE(DTL.UNT_SLS,0)) * COMP.STR_COMP_IND else 0 end) as last_year
```

And then you join back to the original table using `week_num`

Hope you find it useful

Cheers!